# Java camparing two numbers, equality for Primitive

Tags: java, double, long-integer, primitive-types

Question maybe very simple.
Checked the equality of two Primitive types, then got some mistakes.
One of the double, second one long.

```
public class TesterPrimitive {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Equality - " + (5.0 == 5)); // Return true
    System.out.println("Equality - " + (5.000000000000001D == 5L)); // Return false
    System.out.println("Equality - " + (5.0000000000000001D == 5L)); // Return true
}}
```

Why for third equality, for double and long, I got true?
Is it means, long 0 numbers after (.), change any value to absolute 0? Or is it changing bits and then we can get 5.0 for double?

Comment: "Floating point error".

Comment: I think this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744937/how-to-compare-correctly-long-and-float-primitives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-float-double-c-cpp/
double has exactly 15 digits precision. 16th digit gets rounded.

Another thing that is perhaps important to understand - when performing operations on different primitives like here (5.0 == 5), int gets promoted to double for the sake of equality operation. More here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 0):

double variables have a precision of about 15 digits, which is enough for most purposes.double data type can occupy 8 bytes of space in the computer memory and stores 15 to 16 numbers after the decimal point, you can check [this article](https://www.techgeekbuzz.com/blog/float-vs-double/), hope this will help you